# Invalid constructor name

Tags: dart, flutter

bbeginner question here:

I have a class like this

```
class Data {
  String name;
  String imgUrl;
  Data(this.name, this.imgUrl);
}
```

and I'm trying to create a list like this

```
var list = new List<Data>();
var data = new Data("caca", "toto");
list.add(data);
```

But I get an error saying invalid constructor name.
What I'm I doing wrong here?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What line causes this error? Please add the full and exact error message to your question. Did you import the file that contains `class Data {...}` or is all your above code in the same file?

Comment: var list = new List<Data>();  and   artists.add(data); ??

Comment: The Data class is in the same file.
the errors show up on list.add() line

Comment: That line is not related to a constructor in any way. Can you please post a screenshot of the IDE window where it shows the error? Is this from static analysis or do you get the error when you run the code?

Comment: If you are trying in Visual Studio Code this type of things happen sometimes but if run it, will work perfectly and you can try restarting the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your code is not inside a function. Something like:

```
class Something {
  var list = new List<Data>();
  var data = new Data("caca", "toto");
  list.add(data);
}
```

Maybe it's due to one-too-many end braces just above the code, or some other syntactic typo.

Ensure that your code is actually inside the body of a function, not just directly inside the class.

```
class Something {
  void tutu() {
    ...
    var list = new List<Data>();
    var data = new Data("caca", "toto");
    list.add(data);
    ... use list ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right!
Sorry guys. Brainless beginner mistake. I was putting those lines of code at the class level and not in a function.
thank you for your time

Comment: Glad that I could help. Consider marking the question as answered, so other people with the same problem can more easily find the answer.

Comment: Can You please explain a little why we need to define it in a function??

Comment: Dart only allows statements inside function bodies. There is no "top-level code" which is run. In that sense, Dart is just like Java, and not like JavaScript. Outside of that, you can make declarations, but no code which is going to be *executed*. The `list.add(data);` is a statement, so it must be inside a function body. The `var list = ...` and `var data = ...` declarations could appear both inside and outside a function body.